# How can I get a persistent and unresponsive "Are you sure" message to go away?

Tags: notifications, trash

I emptied the trash and the "Are you sure" message won't leave. The trash has been emptied. Neither of the buttons are responsive.

[image]

Any idea what the process is so I can `kill` it?

Comment: You can always restart the finder process a `killall Finder` directly in your terminal.

Comment: @Tolsadus thanks - certainly, I could restart the computer too. I'm curious tho is there is a more specific process to look for... I see a Notification Center and a notifyd (some kind of daemon) in the Activity monitor, but I don't think those pertain specifically to the errant "Are you sure".

Comment: I believe that the Finder process **IS** the process that does this, so it is the one to kill.